# Sylius template rendering exception - channel not found

Tags: symfony, sylius

I just installed a copy of Sylius on my dev server (Ubuntu), configured the database parameters, resolved all dependencies, and ran sylius:install. Install completed successfully, and all looked good.

When trying to access the front-end (web/app_dev.php), however, I get an error thrown during template rendering:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been
>   thrown during the rendering of a template ("Channel could not be
>   found!") in "SyliusWebBundle:Frontend:layout.html.twig" at line 55."
>   at
>   /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php
>   line 182 Context: { "exception": "Object(Twig_Error_Runtime)" }

I'm not entirely sure what channel it's unable to find, or how to resolve this.

Comment: What content do you have in your sylius_channel table?

Comment: This is normally an issue with the channel database table not having an entry or any correct values. Be sure you've installed the sample data and followed the install command properly

Comment: This was indeed the issue, some tables were empty despite the install. Reinstalling fixed the problem, after cloning the repository again (for another reason).

Comment: Could you add the steps you took as an answer for other people to see. I know i've seen the same thing pop up numerous times on the Sylius github issues page.